# Need advice from MongoDB experts/developers before on switching from RDBMS

Tags: sql, mongodb, rdbms, nosql

We have these tables in SQL2005:

- **albums**: video album details (category, title, tags, date, author,
  likes, views etc
- **tags**: album tags & ordered alphabetically(to find all albums w/ a
  particular tag)
- **ratings**: stores the id of the users who rated album(to prevent
  duplicate rating)
- **comments**: stores all comments on the album
- **comment_ratings**: id of the users rated a comment(to prevent duplicate
  rating)
- **comment_replies**: all the replies to a comment with date and poster
  info
- **comment_reply_ratings**: id of the users who rated a reply(to prevent
  duplicate rating)

Can this type of structure be created in MongoDB allowing the
following operations/queries with equal/better performance?

1) Get top 10 most liked albums( title, thumbnail, views, likes,
author & date) with paging.
    If user clicks next, get next 10 most liked album & so on

2) Get top 10 most viewed albums with paging.

3) Get top 10 most discussed albums with paging.

4) Get list of recently created albums with paging but up to 100
albums

5) Get all albums by a given user (title, thumbnail, views,likes,
author & date)

6) Get details of a specific album & show just top 10 comments with
paging.
    Next will load next 10 comments and so on.

7) Get list of related albums. Relation will be done via album tags or
album title

8) Searching by keywords would search the title or tag field of album.

9) When someone clicks a tag, get the list of all albums with that tag

10)When someone clicks a category link, get the list of 10 category
albums

11)Get comments ordered by ratings, date etc

12)Can the order in which new entries made to the document be
controlled?

Thanks for reading. God bless.

Comment: I've moved two applications(first about 100 sql table and second about 60) from different rdbms. Both applications work amazing fast with mongodb. So it's good solution to move your project to mongodb(at least above project, because for some projecs still critical to use sql).

Comment: Bugai, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your reply. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest following structure:

```
Album {
   Id,
   UserId,
   Title,
   Category,
   Tags (list of tag names for fast access and for searching),
   Ratings (user ids, use $addToSet),
   Likes (user ids, use $addToSet),  
   ViewsCount, (probably just integer value,)
   RatingsCount (use $inc to increment this field once someone vote for album),
   CommentsCount (use $inc everytime when someone post comment),
   LikesCount (use $inc everytime when someone click 'Like it')
}

Comment {
   Id,
   AlbumId,
   Text,
   CreatedDate,
   Ratings,
   RatingsCount,
   Replies { (collection of comment replies)
      Text,
      CreatedDate,
      Ratings,
      RatingsCount
   }
}

Tag {
   Id,
   TagName,
   AlbumsCount (use $inc: 1 when new album created with this tag
                 and $inc:-1 - once deleted)
}
```

I've moved comments into separate collections (instead of embed it in album) because for now in mongodb hard to update documents with more then one level of nesting.

Now queries:

1) Get top 10 most liked albums( title, thumbnail, views, likes, author & date) with paging. If user clicks next, get next 10 most liked album & so on

```
db.albums.find().skip(0).limit(10).sort( { RatingsCount: -1 } );
```

2) Get top 10 most viewed albums with paging.

```
db.albums.find().skip(0).limit(10).sort( { ViewsCount: -1 } );
```

3) Get top 10 most discussed albums with paging.

```
db.albums.find().skip(0).limit(10).sort( { CommentsCount: -1 } );
```

4) Get list of recently created albums with paging but up to 100 albums

```
db.albums.find().skip(0).limit(100).sort( { CreatedDate: -1 } );
```

5) Get all albums by a given user (title, thumbnail, views,likes, author & date)

```
db.albums.find({UserId: someUserId})
```

6) Get details of a specific album & show just top 10 comments with paging. Next will load next 10 comments and so on.

```
album = db.albums.find({_id: someAlbumId});
comments = db.comments.find({AlbumId: someAlbumId }).skip(0)
                 .limit(10).sort( { RatingsCount: -1 ,CreateDate: -1 } );
```

7) Get list of related albums. Relation will be done via album tags or album title

*Please clarify*

8) Searching by keywords would search the title or tag field of album.

```
db.albums.find( { $or : [ { Title : searchKey } , { Tags : searchKey } ] } )
```

*Note: Probably need to store tag twice: in lower case for searching, and as is for displaying*

9) When someone clicks a tag, get the list of all albums with that tag

```
db.albums.find( {Tags : { $in: [tagName1, tagName2]}} ] } )
```

*Note: Using $in oprator you can search by multiple tag names.*

10)When someone clicks a category link, get the list of 10 category albums

```
db.albums.find({Category: val }).skip(0).limit(10).sort( { CreatedDate: -1 } );
```

11)Get comments ordered by ratings, date etc

```
db.comments.skip(0).limit(10).sort( { RatingsCount: -1 } );
```

12)Can the order in which new entries made to the document be controlled?

*Please clarify*

I think that now you see that you can move your relational database to MongoDB, and believe your application will be amazing fast with mongodb and above schema ;).

Hope this help.

P.S: If sql 2005 than i suppose you use some .net language?

Comment: Which c# driver you recommend? I one in MongoDB website and another listed here: http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/downloads

Comment: If you have a preferred C# driver, let me know. Otherwise, I will go with https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp

Comment: @Projapati: I suggest you use official mongodb c# driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/downloads). It support by 10gen.

Comment: This driver doesn't have the LINQ dll in it. The driver from samus (community driven) has the linq.dll. Any comment?

Comment: @Projapati: You mean that official driver does not support linq? Yes, it so. But only official driver is stable and contains all latest mongodb features. I use official driver in all my projects, and i can live without linq ;). Make your choice.

Answer (score 4):

I see these sort of questions popping up all over the web. The most common answer you will find is to use the right "tool" for each job, so neither Mongo nor a standard RDBMS will fit every single application better than the rest of the databases, but to my opinion you should definitely invest some time into learning this new "tool" because it will give you an even better perspective on what fits better your mindset and programming style.

I too have recently started using MongoDB after using SQL databases for years and I can tell you it's worth the experience. You can do just about everything with Mongo, most definitely everything you described on your list, but be prepared to make some trade-offs in the process. I don't know what language you're using. I use PHP and I think MongoDB fits PHP much better then any of the SQL databases do in a sense that it organizes data in JSON format, which is more "natural" to PHP (arrays, classes, etc) tree-like structure, which allows to pretty much dump the whole array or a part of it to the DB without having to do a lot of "mapping" and get it back when you need it. In-addition, shema-less design can give you a little more flexibility on how to organize (or not organize :)) your data. Also, if you want to develop a large application, MongoDB will be a lot easier to scale than most SQL DBs.

But for a little more "strict" applications, where data "consistency" and "durability" is more important, I would probably chose one of the old-fashioned RDMBS databases, such as PostgreSQL.
 In fact nothing stops you from using both tools in the same project if you have to.
 Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't data consistency is a must in all web app? I know it is critical in some app (banking system eg.), but in general it is important for sites like this one as well. As long as I can do the above queries with NoSQL type database I am happy to move to the new area. I am dedicating some time to do some good stuff. I am ready for some trade-offs. Thank you for you post.

Comment: not exactly, because Mongo is designed for a scaled environment they do provide so called "eventual" data consistency, which means that your data will be updated eventually on each node which for most web applications is just fine. For example if you create a post on a blog, it should appear on your browser "eventually", which could be 2-5 seconds after you press the post button as opposed to an "instant"! They also do have support for "atomic" operations as well as FSYNC which allows you to get a response  after a certain  number of replicas were updated, which is good enough consistency.

Comment: In practice Mongo is really fast and this delay is usually a lot smaller than 2 seconds, more like few milliseconds, but nevertheless this is one of the little trade-offs I was talking about, but the benefits of using Mongo can outweigh the shortcomings by far for a lot of applications.